# Mod_Rewrite for clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Really simple request. I want my url to look like:

```
http://localhost/movie/72105
```

instead of this

```
http://localhost/movie?id=72105
```

I currently have this setup going on in my .htaccess file, but it does not seem to be working:

```
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just to clarify aswell, when the mod_rewrite is working successfully, I can still use to retrieve the ID?:

```
$_GET['id']
```

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lab/movie/(\d+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, you can browse `http://domain.com/movie/12` and `$_GET['id']` will be `12`.

Comment: I have uploaded to my server to test it, and I get a 404 page when I try it. This works: http://craigcoles.co.uk/lab/movie/?id=72105 but this http://craigcoles.co.uk/lab/movie/72105 doesnt.

Comment: I have added in the RewriteBase  /lab/ - still not working :S

Comment: I edited my answer, put it in `.htaccess` file in root directory!

Comment: can you put rewrite log here?

Comment: I dont know how to access the rewrite log

Comment: what's your server's admin panel?

Comment: My server admin panel is Cpanel

Comment: look for a file named `error_log` in one level top of `public_html`

Comment: [Sat Jul 14 14:49:22 2012] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/lab/movie/72105

Comment: can you put whole content of `.htaccess` file?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/lab/movie/(\d+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

I removed the old Wordpress rewrite rules from the htaccess file and replaced it with this.

Comment: try removing `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  and `</IfModule>`

Comment: can you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: I changed the .htaccess to this and it works `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 1):

I am using this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

you can retrive the id and other parameters (mobvie) by parsing

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

in your index.php than.
also see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html